# Azure Blob, caching a json file not working

Tags: c#, azure

Does anyone have some experience with cache-control on Windows azure. I just can't get it to work. I have a JSON file which I want some caching rules on. I have the following code:

```
            var matchContainer = _blobClient.GetContainerReference(match.ClassContainer);
            matchContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
            matchContainer.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions
                                            {
                                                PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
                                            });
            // save the blob into the blob service   
            string uniqueBlobName = string.Format("matchdata/" + match.KeyPath + ".json").ToLower();
            CloudBlockBlob blob = matchContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(uniqueBlobName);
            var matchString = match.ToString();
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            writer.AutoFlush = true;
            writer.Write(matchString);

            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            blob.UploadFromStream(stream);
            blob.Properties.CacheControl = "max-age=3600, must-revalidate";
            blob.SetProperties();
```

Which is exactly the same as a sample over here
[Sample of setting Cache-Control](http://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/08/11/save-money-by-setting-cache-control-on-windows-azure-blobs/)

The header just doesn't get set. Hope you can help.

Comment: What are you using to see the headers is not getting set?  I used the code you pasted above (only replacing some of the values I didn't have with the match object) and it worked correctly. I verified the header was set using Azure Management Studio and that it was returned during a request using fiddler.

Comment: I use Azure Storage Explorer to chechk the upload result and I use fiddler to check on the request / response. The request does not have any caching info. Request done via ($ajax(..., caching=true...) The response is getting a Cache-Control private (so not the specified setting)

Comment: Ai, I have to rephrase my question. If I check on the Manage.WindowsAzure.Com the Cache-Control is correctly set. Then the problem is Azure returning another header.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using fiddle on windows 8.1 preview, I have noticed that it doesn't always hit the cache. I had to use chrome to validate the cache hit for my blog post.

Alex